# String is unitialized, initialize the variable to silence this warning

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on Caesar cipher on CS50 Week 2. I have generally wrote most part of the code but the final error message which i have not debugged was the initalizing of the string at the end. How do you initialize the string such that the error message goes away and we achieve our objective?

My function is shown below:

```
//Ciphering Function
string plainToCipher(string plainText,int key)
{

int i = strlen(plainText);
string cipher;
int j = 0;
do
{

        if(plainText[j] >= 'a' && plainText[j] <= 'z')
        {
            cipher[j] = ((plainText[j] - 'a') + key) % 26 + 'a'; 
        }

        else if(plainText[j] >= 'A' && plainText[j] <= 'Z')
        {
            cipher[j] = ((plainText[j] - 'A') + key) % 26 + 'A';
        }

}while(j<i);

return cipher;

}
```

I got this error message:

```
caesar.c:71:17: error: variable 'cipher' is uninitialized when used here
  [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
            cipher[j] = ((plainText[j] - 'a') + key) % 26 + 'a'; 
            ^~~~~~
caesar.c:64:18: note: initialize the variable 'cipher' to silence this 
warning
string cipher;
             ^
              = NULL
```

Comment: You declared the variable `cipher`, but didn't set it to anything before attempting to access its contents.  Looks like you're using the variable an an array?

Comment: Or you need to allocate memory for `string cipher;`. I guess that CS50 defines `string` as a pointer, in which case it isn't yet pointing anywhere valid, where you can write. However, the compiler's suggestion `string cipher = NULL;` is flawed, since you cannot dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: What I would do is create cipher outside, as a `char cipher[BUFSIZ]` and the pass it to the function.  Also, try to avoid `string` as much as you can.  It hides information very needed to learn C.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a CS50 data type ostensibly created for `get_string`

Remember from the lecture 2 (around 52:21): a string is an array of `char`s "under the hood". And the computer needs to know where it ends, as discussed in the same lecture at "Null Terminator" (around 1:00:50).

Consider declaring `cipher` an array of `chars`. The number of elements will be the length of the plaintext *plus 1 for the terminating null byte*.